# Form doesn't flow right in the section, instead it goes out of it

Tags: html, css

so my last section of the webpage is like a contact part - it has some text and a table on the left and I added a contact form on the right, but when I float it to the right it goes out of the section, into a blank space. Can someone help and figure out where my mistake is? I have left the CSS and HTML below.

```css
.sayHello {
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: #99ccff;
}

.sayHello div {
 margin: 0px 27% 0px 27%;
}

.sayHello p {
 padding-top: 40px;
 color: snow;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
}

.sayHello h3 {
 color: snow;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 width: 65%;
 text-align: left;
 float: left;
}

.sayHello table {
 float: left;
 border-spacing: 20px;
 color: snow;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.sayHelloTable img {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 padding: 3px;
 background-color: snow;
}

.sayHelloTable td {
 color: snow;
}

.contactForm {
 border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   padding: 20px;
   float: right;
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<section class="sayHello">
  <div>
  
   <p>Say <b>Hello</b></p>
   <br>
   <h3>Don't be shy, drop us an e-mail and say hello! We are a really nice 
    bunch of people. :)</h3>

  </div>

  <table class="sayHelloTable">
   <tr>
    <td><img src="phone.png"></td>
    <td>(416)555-0000</td>
    <td><img src="e-mail-logo.png"></td>
    <td>hello@adeveloping.com</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><img src="twitter.png"></td>
    <td>@NAKATA</td>
    <td><img src="facebook.png"></td>
    <td>@NAKATA</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><img src="80-google-plus-512.png"></td>
    <td>naskuuu123@gmail.com</td>
    <td><img src="pinterest-logo-E994F3A9FB-seeklogo.com.png"></td>
    <td>/NAKATA</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="contactForm">
     <form action="/action_page.php">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
       <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

       <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
       <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

       <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px">            </textarea>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code help you:

```css
.sayHello {
 width: 100%;
 height: 600px;
 background-color: #99ccff;
}

.sayHello .title-wrap {
 margin: 0px 27% 0px 27%;
}

.sayHello p {
 padding-top: 40px;
 color: snow;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
}

.sayHello h3 {
 color: snow;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 width: 65%;
 text-align: left;
 float: left;
}
.contact-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;;
}

.sayHello table {
 float: left;
 border-spacing: 20px;
 color: snow;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
   width: calc(100% - 250px);
}

.sayHelloTable img {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 padding: 3px;
 background-color: snow;
}

.sayHelloTable td {
 color: snow;
}

.contactForm {
   border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   padding: 20px;
   float: right;
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<section class="sayHello">
  <div class="title-wrap">
  
   <p>Say <b>Hello</b></p>
   <br>
   <h3>Don't be shy, drop us an e-mail and say hello! We are a really nice 
    bunch of people. :)</h3>

  </div>
    <div class="contact-wrap">
    
      <table class="sayHelloTable">
        <tr>
          <td><img src="phone.png"></td>
          <td>(416)555-0000</td>
          <td><img src="e-mail-logo.png"></td>
          <td>hello@adeveloping.com</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><img src="twitter.png"></td>
          <td>@NAKATA</td>
          <td><img src="facebook.png"></td>
          <td>@NAKATA</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><img src="80-google-plus-512.png"></td>
          <td>naskuuu123@gmail.com</td>
          <td><img src="pinterest-logo-E994F3A9FB-seeklogo.com.png"></td>
          <td>/NAKATA</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <div class="contactForm">
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <label for="fname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

            <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

            <label for="subject">Subject</label>
             <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px">            </textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main container  has a height of 600px, this is why last child element is out of the section. Try to increase the height to 1000px like this :

```css
.sayHello {
 width: 100%;
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #99ccff;
}

.sayHello div {
 margin: 0px 27% 0px 27%;
}

.sayHello p {
 padding-top: 40px;
 color: snow;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 50px;
}

.sayHello h3 {
 color: snow;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 width: 65%;
 text-align: left;
 float: left;
}

.sayHello table {
 float: left;
 border-spacing: 20px;
 color: snow;
 position: relative;
 bottom: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
  
}

.sayHelloTable img {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
 padding: 3px;
 background-color: snow;
}

.sayHelloTable td {
 color: snow;
}

.contactForm {
 border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
   padding: 20px;
   float: right;
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
}

input[type=text], select, textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<section class="sayHello">
  <div>
  
   <p>Say <b>Hello</b></p>
   <br>
   <h3>Don't be shy, drop us an e-mail and say hello! We are a really nice 
    bunch of people. :)</h3>

  </div>

  <table class="sayHelloTable">
   <tr>
    <td><img src="phone.png"></td>
    <td>(416)555-0000</td>
    <td><img src="e-mail-logo.png"></td>
    <td>hello@adeveloping.com</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><img src="twitter.png"></td>
    <td>@NAKATA</td>
    <td><img src="facebook.png"></td>
    <td>@NAKATA</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><img src="80-google-plus-512.png"></td>
    <td>naskuuu123@gmail.com</td>
    <td><img src="pinterest-logo-E994F3A9FB-seeklogo.com.png"></td>
    <td>/NAKATA</td>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="contactForm">
     <form action="/action_page.php">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
       <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

       <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
       <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

       <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px">            </textarea>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
  </div>
 </section>
```